# SQL Server 2012 - Create Alias from default instance (i.e. '.') to named instance of SQL 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, alias

Scenario is: I have SQL 2012 running as a named instance 'SQL2012'. I can connect to this via SSMS using '.\SQL2012'

Working on a new project, I now want this named instance to be accessible as '.'

To complicate matters, I also have SQL 2014 installed as the default instance, don't need this simultaneously so we can assume this instance is stopped.

I have tried various combinations of alias, the most obvious being:

[image: Sample Alias Combination]

I've also tried setting the port number to the Dynamic Port found in the network configuration, but nothing I've tried so far seems to work.

Is this supported, and if so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, it is possible, and after some more experimentation I figured this out. I *think* the missing elements were:

- Using `.\SQL2012` as the server name instead of `MACHINENAME\SQL2012`
- Ensuring **SQL Server Browser** service is running.

**Full Steps**

- Ensure **SQL Server Browser** service is started, as well as your named SQL2012 instance.
- Open **SQL Server Configuration Manager** on your machine
- Expand the **SQL Server Network Configuration** node, and double click **Protocols for**
- Ensure `TCP/IP` is set to `Enabled`, if it's not, right-click and choose **Enable**
- Double click `TCP/IP`

  - Ensure `Listen All` is set to `Yes`
  - Select the **IP Addresses** tab, and scroll to the bottom. Make a note of the value in **TCP Dynamic Ports**.
  - Press **OK**
- Expand the **SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration** node and double click **Aliases**

  - Right click in white space and select 'New Alias'
  - In `Alias Name`, enter '.'
  - In `Port No`, enter the value you noted earlier from TCP Dynamic Ports.
  - Leave `Protocol` as `TCP/IP`
  - In `Server`, enter `.\<yourinstancename>`
  - Press **OK**
- Repeat the steps for **SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration** for **SQL Native Client 11.0 Configuration (32 bit)**
- Test the connection by using SSMS to attempt to connect to '.'